# UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipe left and finger up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I am using a `UISwipeGestureRecogizer` to swipe `left` and `right` by using `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight` and `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft` and its working totally fine but the default swipe is too sensitive, its just a little bit more than a tap.

Is there any way by which I can make it work like when a `scrollView` works when its `paging enable` property is true that till the user doesnt lifts its finger up, its doesnt work.
 It will be fine if the view doesn't move with the finger moving, and only work when a `left` or `right` gesture is performed and the finger is lifted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` will not give you any option to change the sensitivity or any other aspect of the swipe. To obtain more control over the swipe, you could use one among the following:

**[UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPanGestureRecognizer)**

Here is something to try with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    CGPoint velocity = [gestureRecognizer velocityInView:yourView];
    if(velocity.x > 0){
        //Right gesture
    }else{
        //Left gesture
    }
}
```

**[UIResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html)**

All `UIViews` inherit from `UIResponder`, so you can use the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` method for calculating the touch. Try something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    start = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint end = [touch locationInView:self.view];   
    //Compare start and end points here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you prompt and detailed answer, I'll just try it and let you know.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, but after using it i came to know that this wont fit in my requirement, but the answer is correct, accepted answer and a thumbs up. Thanks :)